# Why mysqld_multi can't start mysql?

Tags: mysql

In my my.cnf, I write:

```
[mysqld_multi]
mysqld = /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.11/bin/mysqld_safe
mysqladmin = /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.11/bin/mysqladmin
user = root
password =

[mysqld1]
pid-file = /usr/local/etc/mysql/mysqld.pid
socket = /usr/local/etc/mysql/mysqld.sock
port = 3306
datadir = /usr/local/var/mysql
log-bin=mysql-bin
server-id=1

[mysqld2]
pid-file = /usr/local/etc/mysql/mysqld1.pid
socket = /usr/local/etc/mysql/mysqld1.sock
port = 3307
datadir = /usr/local/var/mysql1
server-id=2
language=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.11/share/mysql/english
user=mysql
```

Then I execute `mysqld_multi start 2`, and I get the error info:

```
Installing new database in /usr/local/var/mysql1

2016-09-19 19:37:16 [WARNING] mysql_install_db is deprecated. Please consider switching to mysqld --initialize
2016-09-19 19:37:16 [ERROR]   Can't locate the language directory.

FATAL ERROR: Tried to start mysqld under group [mysqld2],
but no data directory was found or could be created.
data directory used: /usr/local/var/mysql1
```

I can't start the mysql process, so what's the problem? It seems the directory `/usr/local/var/mysql1` has some problems, but the directory exists, it's confused.

Comment: did you check directory permissions? it should be "mysql:mysql"
run this command:
chown -R mysql:mysql  /usr/local/var/mysql1

Answer (score 1):

It seems like mysqld_multi wasn't fixed to use `mysqld --initialize`.

You will have to run `mysqld --initialize` along with all directory related options in my.cnf for that server.

(from comment)
You can also fix the `mysqld_multi` script following the instructions in [Running two instances of mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39900497/running-two-instances-of-mysql).

Comment: Or you can do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39900497/running-two-instances-of-mysql (see TIGERB's tip and my comment)