# Running two instances of mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run two instances of MySQL on the same machine and setup my.cnf file as the following:

```
[mysqld1]
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3307
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql

[mysqld2]
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld2.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld2.sock
port        = 3308
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql2
```

When I execute **mysqld_multi start** command, it arises the following error:

> Installing new database in /var/lib/mysql2
>
> 2016-10-06 17:47:23 [WARNING] mysql_install_db is deprecated. Please
>   consider switching to mysqld --initialize 2016-10-06 17:47:23 [ERROR] 
>   Can't locate the server executable (mysqld).
>
> FATAL ERROR: Tried to start mysqld under group [mysqld2], but no data
>   directory was found or could be created. data directory used:
>   /var/lib/mysql2

How can I solve this?

**Note**: MySQL is running on Ubuntu 16.0.4 and MySQL 5.7

Comment: Problem with rights (user?) for the directory /var/lib/mysql2 ? Look at the owner and the rights of /var/lib/mysql. If they are different, change the rights/owner of mysql2 directory.

Comment: I do not know exactly. I work as root.

Comment: The owner should be mysql => chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql2 . Maybe wait for confirmation of better MySQL administrator than me. ;)

Comment: Done but same error.

Comment: You should setup the 2nd server data directory using the `mysqld --initialize` command as the WARNING says.

Answer (score 2):

I know the one question.

```
2016-10-06 17:47:23 [WARNING] mysql_install_db is deprecated. Please consider switching to mysqld --initialize 2016-10-06 17:47:23 [ERROR] Can't locate the server executable (mysqld).
```

Please vim the line 343 to 344&345 in the file /use/bin/mysqld_multi

```
343   #$install_cmd="/usr/bin/mysql_install_db ";
344   $install_cmd="/usr/bin/mysqld ";
345   $install_cmd.="--initialize ";
346   $install_cmd.="--user=mysql ";
347   $install_cmd.="--datadir=$datadir";
```

Comment: I chnaged it to `install_cmd="/usr/sbin/mysqld --initialize` and databases got created

Comment: Note "sbin". There was no mysqld on /usr/bin